# How to read a specific number (or word) from an answer

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I have an .nc file I'm reading in matlab, and getting info out of the time variable.

the code looks like this

```
>> ncreadatt(model_list{3},'T','units')
ans = 
'months since 1850-01-01'
```

what I want to do is get just the `'1850'` out of the answer.

Comment: if the format is consistent then you can just do `ans(12:16)` to get the 12th through 16th  value which would be the year. You can convert it to a number using `str2num(ans(12:16))`

Answer (score 2):

[Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a very powerful tool to parse and manipulate strings.
Matlab has [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) command:

```
line = 'months since 1850-01-01';
res = regexp( line, '\s(\d+)-', 'tokens', 'once');
year = str2double(res{1})
```

And the results is:

```
year = 
1850
```

The regular expression used `'\s(\d+)-'` means:

`\s` - look for a single white space character (the space before `1850`).
`'(\d+)'` - look for one or more digit (`'\d+'`), the parentheses means that all charcters matching here will be saved as a "token".
`'-'` - look for a single `'-'` after the digits.

You can play with it on [ideone](https://ideone.com/veBDXb).